# Find all the verbs after "that" and highlight them

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, wildcard

Basically I am trying to change the past tense into present tense in a word document by finding verbs after the word "that" and replace them with present participle(-ing). The following code working correctly with regular verbs but cannot handle other type of verbs.

The code uses a wildcard search to find instances of "that" followed by a verb in the past tense, and highlights those instances. if I use

```
.TEXT = "that [a-z]@ed>"
```

it only matches regular verbs in the past tense (verbs that end in "-ed"), so it won't match irregular verbs, which can have different forms in the past tense.

To handle irregular verbs, I need to add additional wildcard search patterns to account for the different ways that irregular verbs can be spelled in the past tense. For example, a search pattern for "-t" (for verbs like "left" and "slept"), "-d" (for verbs like "bend" and "send"), "-en" (for verbs like "broken" and "eaten"), etc.

Here is an example of modified code to handle both regular and irregular verbs, This code now search for different past-tense suffixes as well like "-t", "-d" and "-en" and not just "-ed" and this way it can handle all type of verbs.

so to accommodate all the verbs I uses OR with find.

```
    Sub Hi_That_Word_AI()
    Dim AD As Range
    Dim CR As Range
    Dim t, x
    Dim pText$
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    t = Timer
    x = 0
    Set AD = ActiveDocument.Range
    With AD.Find
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .TEXT = "that [a-z]@ed|that [a-z]@t|that [a-z]@d|that [a-z]@en>"
        Do While .Execute
            If Not AD.Sentences(1).TEXT Like "*[.?]”*" Then
                .Parent.Select
                AD.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                x = x + 1
            End If
            .Parent.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
    MsgBox Round(Timer - t, 2) & " Seconds. There are " & x & " instances HighLighted in " & AD.Parent.Name, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Above code does not return any instances due to use of OR with Find method. what is the right way of doing that kind of searched what are the alternate methods?

Comment: In Word you don't have an `OR` within a wildcard search. You have to run separate finds per pattern.

Comment: As Ike said. Nevertheless, you could use an expression like .Text = "that [a-z]@e[dn]>" to find words that end in either ed or en, and .Text = "that [a-z]@[td]>" to find words that end in either d or t.